# In Linux, Which component decides to open a new window in gedit?

Tags: linux, operating-system, gedit, xserver

Let's consider that I open a file with the command `gedit toto1.txt`, a new window shows up with the content of `toto1.txt`. This sound familiar and usual, however the two following cases are not that straight to undertand: (1) a new command (let's says `gedit toto2.txt`) open a new tab in the previous window and (2) a new command (let's says `gedit toto3.txt`) will open a new tab in a new window.

My question is : `which` component decide to open the new window in case (2) and what are the condition to do so ? Why It did not opened a new window in case (1) ?

Any idea ?

Comment: can't reproduce case 2, on my system only the first call of gedit opens a new window, all further calls will be opened as a tab ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's gedit itself that makes that decision. Let's take a look at the source code. The function [open_files](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gedit/tree/gedit/gedit-app.c?h=3.19.5#n420) will open a new window when it cannot find an active window (or when the flag `--new-window` was explicitly specified).

```c
static void
open_files (GApplication            *application,
            gboolean                 new_window,
            ...)
{
        GeditWindow *window = NULL;

        if (!new_window)
        {
                window = get_active_window (GTK_APPLICATION (application));
        }

        if (window == NULL)
        {
                gedit_debug_message (DEBUG_APP, "Create main window");
                window = gedit_app_create_window (GEDIT_APP (application), NULL);

                gedit_debug_message (DEBUG_APP, "Show window");
                gtk_widget_show (GTK_WIDGET (window));
        }

        ...
}
```

So what's an "active window"? Let's look at [get_active_window](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gedit/tree/gedit/gedit-app.c?h=3.19.5#n368):

```c
static GeditWindow *
get_active_window (GtkApplication *app)
{
    GdkScreen *screen;
    guint workspace;
    gint viewport_x, viewport_y;
    GList *windows, *l;

    screen = gdk_screen_get_default ();

    workspace = gedit_utils_get_current_workspace (screen);
    gedit_utils_get_current_viewport (screen, &viewport_x, &viewport_y);

    /* Gtk documentation says the window list is always in MRU order */
    windows = gtk_application_get_windows (app);
    for (l = windows; l != NULL; l = l->next)
    {
        GtkWindow *window = l->data;

        if (GEDIT_IS_WINDOW (window) && is_in_viewport (window, screen, workspace, viewport_x, viewport_y))
        {
            return GEDIT_WINDOW (window);
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

So, the answer is: gedit will open a new window if there's not already a gedit window on screen.

(Well, there could of course be bugs here. I haven't looked very closely. That `viewport_x/y` stuff looks a bit suspect, as a viewport should have four coordinates: top/bottom/left/right. The code might be confused by multi-monitor setups).

Comment: +1. Actually `viewport_x/y` does not sound suspicious to me because I see it as Cartesian coordinates of the top left corner of the window into the viewport (screen).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is done by gedit itself :)
But, if you want to open document in new window you can use --new-window switch. Try to call gedit with --help from command line.
If you need an straight answer on question "How gedit determine is it can use existing window or must open a new one?" i think you must see the gedit source code at https://github.com/GNOME/gedit